# How can I add the JWT authentication in ngx-admin?

Tags: angular, jwt, ngx-admin

I've looking for a while for how I can implement the JWT interceptor and auth guard in the ngx-admin without any success. How can I do that?

I've tried following @WebVbn's tutorial in this thread, [Add JWT automatically for every HTTP request #1375](https://github.com/akveo/ngx-admin/issues/1375), but it didn't work and honestly I'm still kinda new to this whole angular and ngx-admin stuff

Answer (score 0):

that's how to configure it in your front-end to support JWT.

Of course your back-end should support it, and you can configure your routes as you wish, this is just an example

```
  export const NB_CORE_PROVIDERS = [
  ...DataModule.forRoot().providers,
  ...NbAuthModule.forRoot({

    strategies: [

      NbPasswordAuthStrategy.setup({
        name: 'email',
        baseEndpoint:"http://localhost:8080/api/",
      requestPass:false,
      logout:{ 
        endpoint:'auth/logout',
        method:'post',
        requireValidToken:true
      },
      resetPass:{
        endpoint:"auth/reset",
        redirect:{
          success:"/",
          failure:"/auth/login"
        }
      },
      refreshToken:{
        endpoint:'auth/refresh',
        method:"post"
      },
        login: {
          endpoint: 'auth/login',
          method:"post",
          redirect:{
            success:"/pages"
          },
          requireValidToken:true
        },
        token: {
          class: NbAuthJWTToken,
          key:'token'
        }
      }),
    ],
```

Comment: In which component should i put this?

Comment: if you cloned ngx-admin, it's right there at core.module.ts

Comment: How about the registration? how can I add the JWT to my registration page(Sorry i don't know how to exactly explain it)

Comment: As same that I added the login, forget password and logout page.
can you please share you back-end code?

Comment: Btw I tried what you told me and it still doesn't work. Now it doesn't automatically redirect me to the admin dashboard but gets stuck in the login saying email or password is incorrect

Comment: your back-end need to return a valid token in the next structure:
{token:"111.111.111"}